# Facebook account kit crashing in some devices

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk, account-kit

I am using facebook account kit for login in application. Facebook account kit is working fine in most of the devices but in some of the devices. After looking at the crash reports from firebase, i found that most of the devices are Samsung devices. Can someone help me out with this? Any help will be appreciated.

Error Log is :

```
Exception java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myapp.app/com.facebook.accountkit.ui.AccountKitActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int com.facebook.accountkit.ui.bb.ordinal()' on a null object reference
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2521)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2595)
android.app.ActivityThread.access$800 (ActivityThread.java:178)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1470)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:111)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:194)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5631)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:372)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:959)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:754)
arrow_drop_down
Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int com.facebook.accountkit.ui.bb.ordinal()' on a null object reference
com.facebook.accountkit.ui.u.a ()
com.facebook.accountkit.ui.u.a ()
com.facebook.accountkit.ui.cu.onActivityCreated ()
com.facebook.accountkit.ui.co.onActivityCreated ()
android.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated (Fragment.java:2077)
android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState (FragmentManager.java:917)
android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState (FragmentManager.java:1072)
android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState (FragmentManager.java:1054)
android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated (FragmentManager.java:1895)
android.app.Activity.performCreateCommon (Activity.java:6087)
android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:6094)
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1112)
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2468)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2595)
android.app.ActivityThread.access$800 (ActivityThread.java:178)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1470)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:111)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:194)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5631)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:372)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:959)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:754)
```

Answer (score 4):

We just released a new version of Accountkit that should have a fix for this issue. Try updating the AccountKit dependency in your gradle file to this.

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:account-kit-sdk:4.22.1'
```